# OpenCVの開発環境

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, windows-10

OpenCVのカメラ機能を使ってアプリケーション開発をしようと考えています。
そこで、Windows10にOpenCVをインストールしてVisual StudioにOpenCVの環境を設定したところ、Webカメラからの画像が出たりでなかったりとなりました。
特に、release版で画像が表示されないので、困ったことだと思っています。
そこで、OpenCVを安定して利用できる環境について教えて頂けないでしょうか。
例えば、次のように。

OS: ubuntu16.04
OpenCV Version: 3.4.1
言語: C++

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: OSは結局WindowsとUbuntuのどちらなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

**注意: この回答は、ご質問に直接は答えていません。**

2018 年現在の OpenCV はカメラ画像の処理に FFmpeg や DirectShow など多くのバックエンドが使えるようになっており、そのどれかで認識できれば後は `cv::VideoCapture` として抽象化して利用できるようになっています (参考: [Video I/O with OpenCV Overview](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html))。

このため、バックエンド側で認識できる多くのカメラは OpenCV でも同様に使えることが期待されています。実際 OpenCV は多くの環境で動作したことが報告されており、それらを全列挙することは現実的でないように思います。

一応、2013 年時点の古い OpenCV Wiki には、[OpenCV の動作が確認できた環境の一覧](https://web.archive.org/web/20120815172655/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS/)があったようです。しかし現在このページは無く、また私が検索した限りでは類似の公式ページは存在しないようでした。

また、ご自身の環境で OpenCV と互換するカメラが欲しいということであれば、たとえば返品制度を使って互換するものをお探しになるのは如何でしょうか。

#### 参考: 類似質問

- [openCV compatible webcams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21679461/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Good and compatible webcam to do image processing/computer vision?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19873832/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Does exists a list of compatibles cameras with OpenCV](http://answers.opencv.org/question/118688/does-exists-a-list-of-compatibles-cameras-with-opencv/) -- OpenCV Q&A Forum
- [Camera suggestion](http://answers.opencv.org/question/26192/camera-suggestion/) -- OpenCV Q&A Forum